# Drafts in thunderbird get saved without paragraph breaks

Tags: email, thunderbird, office365, imap

This is a problem when using thunderbird to write a draft, and then use the email application on my phone to schedule send.  The problem is, thunderbird is saving the drafts to the remote server without the desired paragraph spaces.  This is a big deal to me because I have to either re add those paragraph spaces on the email app, or run the risk of sending an unprofessional email.  Both are not viable options for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjePr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Adc7k.png)